mock AsyncReadStream boost for unit tests
I am faced with a situation where we use http::async_read(...) and http::async_write(...) internally in a class that represents an HTTP session. However, if we want to unit test this class, we would prefer not to open a network connection, with a port and a socket to listen on and correspondingly accept the first call via an acceptor.
Rather, I was hoping to "fake" the behavior of the socket via another AsyncReadStream. I've looked into writing my own, but it seems like a difficult task and search did not reveal much help.
What is an example of an AsyncReadStream that could be useful here to simply stream in an HTTP request and subsequently put the response into, for the purposes of unit testing? If none, s there a template of some sort that I could use to write a barebones one with this very minimal "fake" functionality?

You can use classic dependency injection and mock your interface. To be more specific, you would need to show example of the code with your system and calls you try to mock. But in principle every problem of this kind can be brutally solved by writing a kind of class INetworkIface { abstract methods here };.

I'm hoping not to brutally solve it like that @pptaszni . A solution clearly is to do as you say and call these via some sort of http_interface which can be either a mock one or prod., and the prod. would underneath call the functions I described (as opposed to having them inlined and called directly as they are), but I am hoping for a way to leave the functions I mentioned and simply instead use a "mock" AsyncReadStream, as I described.

@pptaszni except it doesn't work like that at all for static parametric polymorphism

It's almost trivial to model the AsyncReadStream/AsyncWriteStream concepts

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncWriteStream.html

The only complexity is from initiating async operations using CompletionToken patterns:
E.g.:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::literals;

struct MockStream {
    using error_code    = boost::system::error_code;
    using executor_type = asio::any_io_executor;
    MockStream(asio::any_io_executor ex) : ex_(std::move(ex)) {}
    executor_type get_executor() const { return ex_; }

    template <typename Token> auto async_write_some(asio::const_buffer buf, Token&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, size_t)>( //
            [fallback = ex_](auto h, auto buf) {
                auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(h, fallback);
                asio::dispatch(ex, [=, h = std::move(h)]() mutable {
                    fmt::print("Simulated write of {} completed\n", buf.size());
                    std::move(h)({}, asio::buffer_size(buf));
                });
            },
            token, buf);
    }

    template <typename Token> auto async_read_some(asio::mutable_buffer buf, Token&& token) {
        return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, size_t)>( //
            [fallback = ex_, ch = mock_data_++](auto h, auto buf) {
                auto ex = asio::get_associated_executor(h, fallback);



                std::fill(asio::buffers_begin(buf), asio::buffers_end(buf), ch);

                asio::dispatch(ex, [=, h = std::move(h)]() mutable {
                    if (ch == 'e') {
                        auto partial = (rand() % buf.size()) / 4;
                        fmt::print("Simulated EOF with {} partial read\n", partial);
                        std::move(h)(asio::error::eof, partial);
                    } else {
                        fmt::print("Simulated read of {} completed\n", buf.size());
                        std::move(h)({}, asio::buffer_size(buf));
                    }
                });
            },
            token, buf);
    }

    asio::any_io_executor ex_;
    char                  mock_data_ = 'a';
};

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    asio::io_context ioc;

    MockStream stream(asio::system_executor{});

    asio::async_write(stream, asio::buffer("Hello world"sv), [](auto ec, size_t n) {
        fmt::print("Write completed with {} and {} bytes written\n", ec.message(), n);
    });

    std::array<char, 10> buf;
    asio::async_read(stream, asio::buffer(buf), [&buf](auto ec, size_t n) {
        fmt::print("Read completed with {} and {} bytes read: {}\n", ec.message(), n, buf);
    });

    asio::streambuf sbuf;
    asio::async_read_until(stream, sbuf, "d", [&sbuf](auto ec, size_t n) {
        fmt::print("Read-until completed with {} and {} bytes read\n", ec.message(), n);
        // std::cout << "Streambuf: " << &sbuf << std::endl;
        sbuf.consume(sbuf.size());
    });

    asio::async_read_until(stream, sbuf, "z", [&sbuf](auto ec, size_t n) {
        fmt::print("Read-until completed with {} and {} bytes read\n", ec.message(), n);
        std::cout << "Streambuf: " << &sbuf << std::endl;
    });

    ioc.run();
}

Printing e.g.

LINKS
Similar implementations here:

https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/develop/include/boost/beast/_experimental/test/stream.hpp#L49


Also, consider just starting a local connection. Perhaps over UNIX domain or pipes.If you really deem transport, buffering and failure modes irrelevant, simply cut out the communication layer altogether. it's a UNIT test after all, why does it depend on IO implementation?

I'm not finding it trivial. I have been attempting to modify your example to work for me. On the two reads where it returns Success for you, I get Undefined error.

Yeah, I meant the interface is trivial (3 functions). Async initiations are not trivial at first. Can you share what you have? You can edit the coliru.

Would it be possible to share what I have in a private manner?

Sure. And, wow. You're the guy asking for the error? That makes more sense. I've updated the answer with a demo of EOF

Thanks. I am very close to having it working, but I'm trying to use io_service for my use case. Is there any way to do that? I am getting static assertion failed: AsyncReadStream type requirements not met.

What do you mean, @user129393192? io_service is deprecated, but it has nothing to with the stream concepts. In case you're using ancient versions of boost, refer to the documentation of your version or upgrade? [I don't think this is "close to having it working", it is like saying your kayak is close to working when it's floating upside down in the stream. I suggest not going against the current too much]

I have been for quite some time. How is it possible for me to message you to share what I have?

My implementation takes an io_service as the parameter for socket construction but it seems like it won't accept that in the place of any_io_executor. I wonder if there is some internal version mismatch. I'm struggling to figure this out and get it working.

There's a version mismatch alright. io_service has been deprecated for a long time. Like I said, look at the documentation for your version of boost, or upgrade.

I did. I've figured it out. Thanks for your help. It's just strange that socket takes io_service (it says my version is 1.73), when the docs say it should only take an executor.

@user129393192 The docs do not say that? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload2.html (e.g. from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html)

Note that even 1.73.0. doesn't even document io_service anymore and that wouldn't compile since Boost 1.66(!!) if  you compile with BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATED. That's Oct 2017.

So, besides moving the goalposts (the question asked about a minimal stream object, not a drop-in replacement for a subset of a given socket type): Minimal version that supports that constructor: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4345f1eebcd60e7f
